# script time out MVC 2 and jquery xhr.responseText is blank

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have set the script time out to 20 mins, for my ajax request. After 10m 5sec, my request times out. Am i doing something wrong here? How can i make this better? I am testing functionality against the staging DB and this is a very slow server.

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 1200;
```

At this time xhr.responseText is blank as well.

```
$.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: url,
                type: Ajax.MethodType.POST, //global.vars.js
                data: { estimateId: estimateId, random: Math.random() },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                    jMessageError(xhr.responseTex, $click, false, true);

                },
                success: function (result) {
                        //display the count
                        $("#" + enumFormFields.hiddenCountNumberId).val(result.Message);
                        $("#" + enumDashboard.estimateVolumeId).html(result.Message);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have specified ajax time out to 20 mins and it still did the same

```
$.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: url,
timeout: 1000 * 60 * 20, //20 mins
                type: Ajax.MethodType.POST, //global.vars.js
                data: { estimateId: estimateId, random: Math.random() },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                    jMessageError(xhr.responseTex, $click, false, true);

                },
                success: function (result) {
                        //display the count
                        $("#" + enumFormFields.hiddenCountNumberId).val(result.Message);
                        $("#" + enumDashboard.estimateVolumeId).html(result.Message);

                }
            });
```